# (Formatting) A single indent in VSCode is two indents in repl.it Is there a setting for this on either one of the IDEs?

Tags: python, formatting, indentation, replit

This python code was imported from a git repository in which the code was originally written from Visual Studio Code. Seeing the code on repl.it, the indentations are now corrupted (They don't see to agree on the indentations).

A single indentation in VSCode is two indentations in repl.it I'm not sure if anybody knows if there's a setting or anything to make them the same.

Code from VSCode
[image]

Code from Replit (Indentation lines are double from what it's supposed to be)
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to "settings" on repl.it and change the indentation size, in this case, it's 4

[image]

Comment: Vscode has a similar setting, if I remember correctly its in the bottom right corner.